# BoundaryCallback in PageList never gets called

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I'm using `Paging Library` with `PagedListAdapter`, I'm using `BoundaryCallback` in `PagedList` to know when the user reaches the end of the list. The problem is that the method in my callback never gets called.

This is my data source code:

```
class PropertyDataSource : ItemKeyedDataSource<Int, Property>() {

    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<Int>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Property>) {
        callback.onResult(getProperties(1, params.requestedLoadSize))
    }

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Property>) {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        callback.onResult(getProperties(params.key + 1, params.requestedLoadSize + params.key))
    }

    override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Property>) {

    }

    override fun getKey(item: Property): Int {
        return item.id
    }
}
```

my code for boundary callback is

```
class MyBoundryCallBack: PagedList.BoundaryCallback<Property>() {
    override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: Property) {
        Log.e("alz", "at end $itemAtEnd")
    }

    override fun onItemAtFrontLoaded(itemAtFront: Property) {
        Log.e("alz", "at front $itemAtFront")
    }

    override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
        Log.e("alz", "zero item loaded")
    }
}
```

here is my activity code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val adapter = MyListAdapter(PropertyDiffCallback())

    mainRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    mainRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    val propertyDataSourceFactory = PropertyDataSourceFactory()

    val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setPageSize(2)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(3)
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .build()

    val pagedList = LivePagedListBuilder(propertyDataSourceFactory, config)
            .setBoundaryCallback(MyBoundryCallBack())
            .build()

    pagedList.observe(this, Observer {
        adapter.submitList(it)
    }
}
```

And my code for Adapter is look like this

```
class MyListAdapter(diffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Property>) : 
    PagedListAdapter<Property, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(diffCallback) {

    class ItemHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val titleTV: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return ItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_property, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if(getItem(position) == null) return

        val itemHolder = holder as ItemHolder
        itemHolder.titleTV.text = getItem(position)!!.title
    }
}
```

And here is my implementation of `getProperties()` that will return some mock data. Later on, I'm going to change it to load data from the server.

```
fun getProperties(from: Int, to: Int): List<Property> {
    val list = ArrayList<Property>()
    for (i in from..to){
        list.add(Property(i, "item $i"))
    }
    return list
}
```

Note that, my code works fine and my adapter requesting more data as it goes to the end, I just don't get the callback when PagedList gets to the end.

Comment: @pskink I've seen google sample but I can't figure out the difference. It seems that they do the same thing, `define a callback and assign it to the builder class`

Comment: @pskink is simply a method that returns mock data. so get properties(1,4) will return 3 new items with ids from 1 to 3. I'm going to replace it later with logic to load data from server

Comment: @pskink I don't see how the code is different from mine. I also edited my answer and included the implementation of `getProperties()` method.

Comment: @pskink thank you, I see the problem now. I assumed that boundary callback has to get called whenever the last or first item on my partial list is gets called but I see now that It gets called whenever it reaches the end of data in data source!

Comment: @pskink I still have a problem figuring out a way to find out we reached at the end of the list I've already have loaded, I need this to figure out when my adapter showing last item so I can do things like show/hide progress bar. I know this can be done with custom callbacks in my data source or even in adapter but I was looking for a nicer more generic way.

Comment: Have you found any working solution? Same problem for me.

Comment: @romaneso Well,  I added this as a bug to the Google issue tracker and now they marked it as fixed! I didn't check out the fix yet because I'm working on something else but you can take a look yourself. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111408341

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Still, the error somehow is present for me. Not always, but sometimes the callback just doesn't get called. Somehow strange behaviour.